# Angular hide/show based on radio button

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

[**Plunke**r](http://plnkr.co/edit/qkh2ajdN4dNm3LOf5qpr?p=preview)

How can i make yes radio button to be checked on page load and show/hide the field-set accordingly. Currently on load radio button is checked but its not showing the fieldset.

Html

```
  <form name="myform" class="form "  novalidate >
 <fieldset>
       <span>Would you like a receipt sent to you?</span>
     <ul class="vList">
      <li>
        <input type="radio" name="receiptConfirmation" id="receiptAffirm"  ng-model="reciept" value="yes" ng-checked="true">
        <label class="form__radioLabel" for="receiptAffirm:" >Yes</label>
      </li>            
         <li>
      <input type="radio" name="receiptConfirmation" id="receiptDeny" ng-model="reciept" value="no">
            <label class="form__radioLabel" for="receiptDeny">No </label>
        </li>
   </ul>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="fieldset" ng-show="reciept=='yes'">
    <legend class="isVisuallyHidden">Email Receipt</legend>
      <ul class="vList">
       <li>
         <label for="firstName" class="form__label">First Name</label>
         <input id="Text4" class="form__input form__input--textfield" type="text" >
      </li>
         <li>
           <label for="emailAddress" class="form__label">Email Address</label>                                           
           <input id="email1" class="form__input form__input--textfield" type="email">
        </li>
     </ul>
 </fieldset>


</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not mix `ng-checked` with `ng-model`. Setting ng-checked will not update the model, it will just update the element's checked property. Instead set the ng-model `reciept` to the desired value.

Remove ng-checked from input:-

```
 <input type="radio" name="receiptConfirmation" id="receiptAffirm"  
        ng-model="reciept" value="yes">
```

In your controller set the model:-

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
 $scope.reciept = "yes";
});
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/8awp9H?p=preview)**

Comment: thanks for the hint, I upvoded your answer since it's more appropiate, cheers!

Comment: @jack.the.ripper Sorry. But i see a lot of ng-init usage where it is not really intended to be used as documented.. :( .. Thanks though!!

Answer (score 0):

Just set `$scope.reciept = 'yes';` in your controller?

You have spelt receipt wrong also.